# how to use a font from google font just to be used in one react component with material UI?

Tags: reactjs, import, material-ui, google-fonts

i got only one Typography element that uses a different font than the rest of the application , could someone advise what's the best way to get the font from google font website  for jus this component.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use google font, the easiest way is to add the cdn link in the `<head>` of your html. Then you may use like this:

```
<Typography sx={{fontFamily: "Merriweather" }}>
  Sample Text
</Typography>
```